# Is "mount --bind dir1 dir2" an alternative for hard links for directories?

Tags: mount, hard-link

It's a known fact that you cannot create hard links for directories.

My question is whether can one use `mount --bind dir1 dir2`

instead of creating a hardlink of dir1 to dir2? *which can't happen*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with `mount --bind` you can make the same content (especially directories) appear in the file system twice.

For a very comprehensive article about this please see [What is a bind mount?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198591/29882)  on unix.stackexchange.com

Most important points:

1. Bind mounts are "just" an alternate way of viewing the contents of the file system.
2. They may cross filesystem boundaries and span `chroot` jails.
3. You can use them for directories (for instance to prepare a `chroot` by providing access to the `/proc`, `/sys` and `/dev` file systems (see [mount dev, proc, sys in a chroot environment?](https://superuser.com/a/417004/185152)  on superuser.com)
4. Quoted from Gilles' answer I mentioned above:

> Unlike a hard link or symbolic link, a bind mount doesn't affect what is stored on the filesystem. It's a property of the live system.

Comment: I've tried it and contents are shadowed by mount to/over subfolder performed after that. I think I need to get and copy link to directory. https://superuser.com/questions/1682518/is-it-possible-to-access-files-in-a-folder-shadowed-by-a-mount-not-moving-ent